# how to add text to textarea in js

Tags: javascript, html

I am having trouble adding text to a text editor on my website hokuco.com .
Here is what I have;

please try my example, you will see that the text box contains text, I want that to be automatically added in java script , and the person who edits the code will not see it

```html
<div class = "fixed">
<center>
<table>
 <tr><td>Type here</td></tr>
 <tr>
  <td colspan="3">
   <textarea id="inputTextToSave" style="width:512px;height:256px">
   &lt;html&gt; 
   &lt;body&gt; 
   &lt;link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ceedweb.css" /&gt;
   &lt;!--type down there, by the way, this is a comment tag you won't need it--&gt;
   
   
   &lt;body&gt;
   &lt;/html&gt;
   </textarea>
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>Save As:</td>
  <td><input id="inputFileNameToSaveAs"></input></td>
  <td><button onclick="saveTextAsFile()"><img src="fl.gif" Save</button></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>Select file Load:</td>
  <td><input type="file" id="fileToLoad"></td>
  <td><button onclick="loadFileAsText()">Load File</button><td>
 </tr>
</table>
</center>
<hr>
<script type='text/javascript'>

function saveTextAsFile()
{
 var textToWrite = document.getElementById("inputTextToSave").value;
 var textFileAsBlob = new Blob([textToWrite], {type:'text/html'});
 var fileNameToSaveAs = document.getElementById("inputFileNameToSaveAs").value;

 var downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
 downloadLink.download = fileNameToSaveAs;
 downloadLink.innerHTML = "Download File";
 if (window.webkitURL != null)
 {
  
  downloadLink.href = window.webkitURL.createObjectURL(textFileAsBlob);
 }
 else
 {
  
  downloadLink.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(textFileAsBlob);
  downloadLink.onclick = destroyClickedElement;
  downloadLink.style.display = "none";
  document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
 }

 downloadLink.click();
}

function destroyClickedElement(event)
{
 document.body.removeChild(event.target);
}

function loadFileAsText()
{
 var fileToLoad = document.getElementById("fileToLoad").files[0];

 var fileReader = new FileReader();
 fileReader.onload = function(fileLoadedEvent) 
 {
  var textFromFileLoaded = fileLoadedEvent.target.result;
  document.getElementById("inputTextToSave").value = textFromFileLoaded;
 };
 fileReader.readAsText(fileToLoad, "UTF-8");
}

</script>
</div>
```

Comment: a textbox is only to display text, your editor needs to have designmode on or if its a div, then contenteditable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the contents of that textarea to be added to the user's input without them appearing inside the textarea, you could simply perform string concatenation on the value of your textarea before processing it further:

```
var textToWrite = 'stuff that comes before';
textToWrite += document.getElementById("inputTextToSave").value;
textToWrite += 'stuff that comes after';
// And then do all the rest.
var textFileAsBlob = new Blob([textToWrite], {type:'text/html'});
```

Comment: No worries! Glad I could help.